# Trouble Loading .wasm Files in HTML from a Golang File Server

Tags: html, go, web, webassembly, fileserver

I'm working on creating a sub-url for my file server in Golang.

The Golang function code I have is:

```golang
func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../../dist/"))
    
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.Handle("/a/", http.StripPrefix("/a/", fs))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}
```

In the `"../../dist/"` directory, there is one `index.html` and several `.wasm` files. When I access `:8081/`, the file server works correctly. However, when I attempt to access `:8081/a/`, it finds the index.html but fails to load the `.wasm` files which are supposed to be loaded in HTML.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="/start-4f9b00c561355aee_bg.wasm" as="fetch" type="application/wasm" crossorigin="">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/start-4f9b00c561355aee.js">
</head>
<body>

    <script type="module">
    import init from '/start-4f9b00c561355aee.js';
    init('/start-4f9b00c561355aee_bg.wasm');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding `http.StripPrefix` (as seen in the code above), even adding `Header().Set("content-type", "application/wasm")`, but neither of these steps seems to allow `/a/` to load properly.

Do I miss something? Thanks.